# Ubuntu 12.04 - Wake issue from suspend. Acer Aspire One 722

Tags: 12.04, suspend, ati, aspire-one

Same issue as on Ubuntu 11.11 the Aspire 722 won't wake from suspension.
This time the fixes for 11.11 are not applicable, Jupiter 0.1.2 isn't helping.

I have tried both the Opensource drivers and the ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver. ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates) for some reason won't install on my machine, and times out on install.

Anyone had similar issues or advice?

I have yet to write a bug report and am a little confused as to how I could, as the computer needs to be restarted to get anything back on the screen.

So my only option is to disable suspend altogether, which is not very practical on a laptop, as you can imagine.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Ed

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I have filed a bug report **Ubuntu “pm-utils” package Bugs Bug #999638** if any have a similar issue it can be found at: (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/999638)  Thanks guys.

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: A fix is now available, if you update to the AMD catalyst 12.10 -- information can be found at the bug report (above).